# Angular Error TS7006: Parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 17 client application with an AccountService for login, account.service.ts, with the method login() (see code further down) and a nav component, nav.component.ts, which uses that service and thus also has a login method (again, see code further down). The client application is calling the back-end login functionality through an API (REST), which I have tested in Postman without errors. I get the following error when I try to run from the Angular client application:

```
X [ERROR] TS7006: Parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/nav/nav.component.ts:24:13:

      24 │       error: error => console.log(error)
```

My nav.component.ts class looks like the following (without the imports in the top):

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  model: any = {};
  loggedIn = false;

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  login() {
    this.accountService.login(this.model).subscribe({
      next: response => {
        console.log(response),
        this.loggedIn = true
      },
      error: error => console.log(error)
    })
  }
}
```

I first tried to declare the 'error' variable with the 'any' keyword, i.e.:

```
error: (error: any) => console.log(error)
```

and then just got the same error but for the variable 'response' instead:

```
X [ERROR] TS7006: Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/nav/nav.component.ts:20:12:

      20 │       next: response => {
```

Ok I thought, let's declare that one as an 'any' as well, i.e.

```
next: (response: any) => {
        console.log(response),
        this.loggedIn = true
      },
```

But then I just got another error:

```
X [ERROR] TS2339: Property 'login' does not exist on type 'AccountService'. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/nav/nav.component.ts:19:24:

      19 │     this.accountService.login(this.model).subscribe({
```

So I returned to my original code and removed the 'any'-declarations and instead went to my tsconfig.json file and set the compilerOptions setting 'strict' to false, i.e.:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,

(etc)
```

Then I got rid of the original error saying that 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type, but instead got back to the last error saying that Property 'login' does not exist on type 'AccountService'. My account.service.ts looks like the following:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {
  baseUrl = 'https://localhost:5001/api/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(model: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', model);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The compiler would be more help if you gave it more information - https://angular.io/guide/http-request-data-from-server#requesting-a-typed-response. I'd also recommend linting to explicitly require method return types, rather than leaving everything to be inferred.

Comment: you're subscribing so it seems like you should have... login(model: any): Observable<any> {...} Or better yet, : Observable<YourType> That's going to be what's returned... an observable of YourType. (Observable has those next and error notifications) 
 Since you're not typing anything it's implicitly typing to any. The last error is a little weird... it's looking for a property instead of a method.

Comment: This error was so weired. I tried several possible solutions I found here on StackOverflow, including what was suggested in your suggestion @Yong Shun. I'm developing in VS Code, and in the end I went back to my original solution, re-compiled everything, made sure I had the correct versions of packages and so on, restarted everything, and then it just worked. So thank you so much for your time.